# How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile-application

I've built my app, I can run it on my local emulator (and also on my android device within the same network by changing debug server).

However, I want to build an APK that I can send to someone without access to the development server and I want them to be able to test application.

I see there is a section Using offline bundle on iOS section of the documentation. But I couldn't figure out how to accomplish the same for android. Is this possible? If so, how?

**UPDATE:** On the answer to this question ([Android failed to load JS bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle)) it is said that offline bundle can be downloaded from development server. But when I obtain the bundle from development server the image files can't be loaded.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

Following Aditya Singh's answer the generated (unsigned) apk would not install on my phone. I had to generate a signed apk using the instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android).

The following worked for me:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Place the `my-release-key.keystore` file under the `android/app`
directory in your project folder. Then edit the file
`~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and add the following (replace ****
with the correct keystore password, alias and key password)

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=****
```

If you're using MacOS, you can store your password in the keychain using the instructions [here](https://pilloxa.gitlab.io/posts/safer-passwords-in-gradle/) instead of storing it in plaintext.

Then edit app/build.gradle and ensure the following are there (the sections with signingConfigs signingConfig may need to be added) :

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

*Then* run the command `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` ,

*For Windows* 'cd android' and then run `gradlew assembleRelease` command , and find your **signed** apk under `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`, or `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

Comment: app-release.apk is not installing. what would be the issue?

Comment: I create the apk, upload to google play, but it not working... some hint?

Comment: I can't find the android/app folder, where is this located?

Comment: @DHLopez it should be in your project folder root

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't, but I found it was because I am using expo for testing, and the create native app npm has a different structure, so for future reference, if anyone gets this problem, just eject your project and then you get those folders, funny how the tutorial tells you to use npm to create the app, and then talks about a structure that doesn't exist when you use it

Comment: @DHLopez Thanks for answering my question :-) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367683/insufficient-docs-for-my-task

Comment: Thanks @DHLopez. For completeness, [here's the docs on ejecting](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app)

Comment: On Windows, you may need to open a command line as administrator to run this command inside the JDK folder due to restriction of permissions for creating the keystore file.

Comment: What is the key password here? The store password is what you enter during the key generation steps but I didn't use any other password..

Comment: @Neurion that link 404s, the current documentation on ejecting with expo is here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/workflow/customizing/

Comment: Release apk build successfully, but release apk is crashing when I install it on my phone. Please help

Comment: Build successful but no APK.. wtf.. android.

Comment: Or `:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: hey, if I have to build again the same command `./gradlew bundleRelease` is not generating apk. any idea why?

Comment: @Azeez to generate an apk, you need to use ```./gradlew assembleRelease``` command. bundleRelease will only generate an .aab file. Refer this for more info 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576462/gradlew-bundlerelease-doesnt-generate-release-apk-in-react-native

Answer (score 241):

You will have to create a key to sign the apk. Use below to create your key:

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-key.keystore -alias my-app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Use a password when prompted

Once the key is generated, use it to generate the installable build:

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Generate the build using gradle

```
 cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Upload the APK to your phone. The `-r` flag will replace the existing app (if it exists)

```
adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
```

A more detailed description is mentioned here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

**UPDATE**: Based on comments by @shashuec and @Fallen

if you get error

```bash
error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'
```

run

```bash
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked for me. The only issue I got was this message: "Missing required arguments: bundle-output" en the react-native-bundle part, but is solved by deleting the 2 "\" symbols

Comment: I am amazed by the poor documentation of Facebook where they totally omitted the `react-native bundle` part. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am working with windows, works with this `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` as well.

Comment: I get this error `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
`.  when I try to install the apk.

Comment: @developernaren were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @DanielBarde I had a test build installed on my mobile before, it worked after I uninstalled that.

Comment: Also getting `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`. I have uninstalled the existing app. Any solution?

Comment: adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
5663 KB/s (8971275 bytes in 1.546s)
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release-unsigned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: @JoshPinter were you able to find a solution?

Comment: They didn't skip the bundle process...they just forgot to tell you to uncomment the lines in the gradle file! Wow...

Comment: @SofianeBelhadjKacem I did, yes. Thankfully. I actually used a Signed APK file and installed that instead, which I generated from Android Studio. Here were my steps: **1) Generate React Native bundle:** `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/<your-package-name>/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/<your-package-name>/src/main/res/` **2) Generate a Signed APK file from Android Studio.** **3) Install Signed APK File to USB device:** `adb -d install -r <path_to_signed_apk>` **4) Profit!**

Comment: You can use this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config

Comment: How can i generate a signed APK file from Android Studio !

Comment: if you get error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'`

run `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`

Comment: Yep.. none of these work. Signing from ReactNative's official website or @JoshPinter 's lovely advice. I keep getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly` .

Comment: These steps only gave me an unsigned APK, which didn't install on my phone. I've added the steps that worked for me (to generate a signed APK) as a separate answer below.

Comment: While in new RN version there is one entry point (index.js) you need to use this flag `--entry-file index.js` instead of `index.android.js`

Comment: I am getting build issues despite following these steps, the issue is in only for release build, where as debug build is fine. Error is as follows FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Development/SourceCode/MobApp/testApp/root-state/sock'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: @aditya-singh, can you please add shashuec's comment to your answer?

Comment: if you have index.js in project root instead of index.android.js then run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: If you have `Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'android'.` then you need to run from root dir `expo eject`

Comment: Thank you this is well explained compared to the react native docs

Answer (score 55):

You should just use android studio for this process. It is just simpler. But first run this command in your react native app directory:

For Newer version of react-native(e.g. react native 0.49.0 & so on...)

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

For Older Version of react-native (0.49.0 & below)

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Then Use android studio to open the 'android' folder in you react native app directory, it will ask to upgrade gradle and some other stuff. go to build-> Generate signed APK and follow the instructions from there. It's really straight forward.

Comment: I also use Android Studio and Xcode to build release versions for my React Native apps... but the android generation could be done with a script as described by @Aditya Singh

Comment: This is no longer needed https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d

Answer (score 52):

If any one want to build without playstore keys then this command would be very helpful.

`# react-native run-android --variant=release`

After build complete you can find the apk in release build file.

Comment: the APK you're looking for will be located inside `/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`

Comment: Can someone use the apk generated by this method to restore the react-native code ?

Answer (score 49):

Run this command:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

> Note that `--variant=release` is only available if you've set up signing
>   with `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Comment: @jasan I found another issue like yours here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11586

This may fix the issue:

cd android && ./gradlew installRelease

Comment: I tried `cd android && ./gradlew installRelease` and got this error `Task 'assembleRelease.' not found in root project 'project'. Some candidates are: 'assembleRelease'.`

Comment: Yes, You have to generate the Keystore file. and edit the gradle file.Follow those instructions to fix this issue. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Answer (score 27):

for React Native 0.49 and over

you should go to project directory on terminal and run that command

```
1 - mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2 - react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

if under 0.49

```
  1 - mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
  2 - react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then Use android studio to open the 'android' folder in you react native app directory, it will ask to upgrade gradle and some other stuff. go to build-> Generate signed APK and follow the instructions from there. That okey.

Comment: This is an easy way to do it if you have Android Studio installed (which will take care of using or creating the Keystore). Thanks.

Comment: Hey.. have a quick question.. are the above steps required ? The react native doc does not mention it anywhere..

Comment: @pravin it is not required, it is one of the method of the generate apk.

Answer (score 17):

Try below, it will generate an app-debug.apk on your root/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug folder

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

then go to android folder and run

`./gradlew assembleDebug`

Comment: The APK generated here needs Metro to run...so I think that's still using the dev server

Answer (score 14):

#### If you get `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`.

I tried using @Aditya's method of generating an unsigned APK file and installing that, but when I went to install it on my Android tablet, it gave me an error of `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`.

I imagine this is because the APK file wasn't signed and the tablet was not happy with this. So, after generating the React Native bundle file I was able to generate a signed APK file, as normal, via Android Studio.

*By the way, our app is a fully functioning Android app that already exists in the Play Store and we are just adding React Native to it in bite-sized pieces, because it's awesome.*

So to summarize, here were my steps:

**1) Generate React Native bundle:**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/<your-package-name>/src/main/assets/index.android.bu‌​ndle --assets-dest android/<your-package-name>/src/main/res/
```

**2) Generate a Signed APK file from Android Studio.**

**3) Install Signed APK File to USB device:**

```
adb -d install -r <path_to_signed_apk>
```

*The `-d` flag just tells `adb` to install on the usb device attached, in the event that you have an emulator running as well. If you want to install on whatever an emulator, drop the `-d` flag.*

**4) Profit!**

Answer (score 12):

Go to project directory and run the command:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: This will generate an unsigned apk if you didn't do required configuration (like Pedram told).

Comment: It will create debug, release and unsigned apk in generated folder. My intention was to share release apk.

Answer (score 10):

Hopefully it will help new beginners

Official doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

If you dont have keystore than use before command else skip

**Generating a signing key / Keystore file**
You can generate a private signing key using keytool. On Windows keytool must be run from C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

you will get a file like **my-release-key.keystore**

**Setting up gradle variables**
Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app directory in your project folder.
Edit the file android/gradle.properties and add the following (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key password),
enableAapt2 set false is workaround , as android gradle version 3.0 [problem](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3097)

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****

android.enableAapt2=false
```

then add these app/buid.gradle (app)

below default config

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
```

**and Inside Build type release { }**

```
 signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

**then simply run this command in android studio terminal** 
Below commands will automate above all answers

if windows

```
cd android
gradlew assembleRelease
```

if linux / mac

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

if you got any error delete all build folder and run command

```
gradlew clean
```

than again

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: omg `gradle clean`...I have been struggling with this for a while getting those build errors, thank you so much for this answer!!

Comment: how to upload the Keystore file on the play store console?

Comment: @AhsanAbrar first thing its optional!! then you dont upload, play console will generate sha keys for you and automatically sign your apps. generally people develop keystore file using android studio and then sign it at their end and upload signed apk to playstore. but in that case you have to safely store keystore app to do future uploads.

Answer (score 8):

I have another solution:-
Generating a signing key
You can generate a private signing key using keytool. On Windows keytool must be run from C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app directory in your project folder.

Edit the file android/app/build.gradle in your project folder and add the signing config,

```
android {
....
signingConfigs { 
  release { 

      storeFile file('my-release-key.keystore') 
      storePassword 'yourpassword' 
      keyAlias 'my-key-alias' 
      keyPassword 'yourpassword' 

  } 
}}}


buildTypes {release {signingConfig signingConfigs.release}}
```

and run

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

This will give you two files at android\app\build\outputs\apk
app-release.apk and app-release-unsigned.apk
now install the app-release.apk in your android device.

Comment: Where is the android\app folder? I don't see it under my project (I only see node_modules, and inside of it, there's no android/app)

Comment: @DHLopez you have to use the pure React Native project to have access to the android folder. If you're using Expo, then you have to detach the Expo project using expo eject.

Answer (score 8):

If you get an error involving index.android.js. This is because you are using the new React-native version (I am using 0.55.4)
Just replace the "index.android.js" to "index.js"

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Answer (score 6):

First

```
cd android
```

then Run

```
./gradlew installRelease
```

Finally You will able to find the apk here.

```
Project\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release.apk
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use `installRelease` here?

Answer (score 6):

> For me this worked (MACOS)

**Open terminal**

```
cd project_directory
```

run this command

```
yarn start
```

**Open another terminal**

run these commands

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 5):

### The GUI way in Android Studio

- Have the Android app part of the React Native app open in Android Studio (this just means opening the android folder of your react-native project with Android Studio)
- Go to the "Build" tab at the top
- Go down to "Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)"
- Then select "Build APK(s)"
- This will walk you through a process of locating your keys to sign the APK or creating your keys if you don't have them already which is all very straightforward. If you're just practicing, you can generate these keys and save them to your desktop.
- Once that process is complete and if the build was successful, there will be a popup down below in Android Studio. Click the link within it that says "locate" (the APK)
- That will take you to the apk file, move that over to your android device. Then navigate to that file on the Android device and install it.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

- Some useful script for WINDOW Users

Copy-paste these code in package.json file under  *`"script":{}`*

```
 * VS Code
   --Enable NPM SCRIPT

   --Now you can directly run scripts from here


    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "clean-run-android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd.. && react-native run-android  ",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache",
    "reset": "rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clear && watchman watch-del-all && npm i",
    "debug-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd app/src/main/res/ && rmdir /S /Q raw && rmdir /S /Q drawable-mdpi",
    "release-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd..",
    "install-apk": "cd android && ./gradlew installRelease",
    "release-aab": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease"
```

Answer (score 4):

For latest react native versions to bundle the project

**Android**

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

**iOS**

`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

Answer (score 3):

For me `./gradlew assembleRelease` does not work anymore but the following does.

```
./gradlew :app:assembleRelease
```

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/notifee/react-native-notifee/issues/151#issuecomment-696910951).

Answer (score 2):

## Generate debug APK without dev-server

If you really want to generate a debug APK (for testing purpose) that can run without the development server, Here is the link to my answer to another similar post which may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762142/7755579

All you've to do is:

1. edit `android/app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
    ...
    bundleInDebug: true, // add this line
]
```

2. run this command at the root directory of your project

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

3. Then, run `./gradlew assembleDebug` (Mac or Linux) or `gradlew assembleDebug` (Windows) inside `/android` folder
   *If the build failed, I suggest you to build the application from Android studio*

Answer (score 2):

Only this worked for me - `yarn android --variant=release`

Answer (score 0):

Using android studio to generate signed apk for react's android project is also a good and easy option , open react's android project in android studio and generate keystroke and signed apk.

Answer (score -3):

Refer the react-native official documentation on Generating Signed APK

[React-Native Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

Comment: This is not a good answer, even if it did address the user's question which it does not. They want to build a standalone debug APK, not a release one.