# Package React Native App on Windows

Tags: react-native

Please does any one here have an idea how to package a react native app on windows? I need to send the APK for a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some long research i found two things put together that make it work.

Facebook's doc is great but the left out the part where you will need to bundle your app before building.
Follow this to find out how to bundle your app.
[Bundle App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)

Follow this to find out the proper way yo generate your signed key and build the APK.
[Generate signed Key and build apk](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

NB: This answer solves the problem for Android developers on windows.