# react-native run-android and react-native start

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Do I have to run `react-native run-android` and `react-native start` in my command prompt every time time I reopen my project and emulator?

-- Thanks

Comment: Dint get it Henrik? .

Answer (score 6):

You usually do. The `react-native run-android` command might be optional if you do not want to deploy the android native code again (for instance, if you have not made any changes). You will have to launch the application manually and it will try to connect to the packager that starts with `react-native start`. I am not sure if you can bundle the JS for offline use in debug mode. Maybe you can try the same procedure as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935409/2628463), but with `assembleDebug` in order to avoid that one.

Comment: Thank you will try that. Also do you have any idea about how to open Developers menu in Android studio emulator. I wanted to switch on to Hot reloding. But by pressing F2 my menu does not pop up.

Comment: Try Ctrl+m or in your console, `adb shell input keyevent 82`