# npm start command in React native

Tags: react-native

What actually do the 'npm start command' when run react app on a physical device.  Is it mandatory to write this command to run react app on a real device? If Yes then why and if No why?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350660/react-native-run-android-and-react-native-start

Answer (score 0):

For apps created with [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app), the command is `npm start`.

Non-crna apps are run on a physical device by connecting the device, executing any necessary [authorization steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) and running either `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`.

Comment: My concern is when run my application on emulator I don't give "npm start" command and it's execute successfully but in real device it's showing error I need to understand the difference between these two's.