# Expo - Build in local

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I have a question and I didn't find a clear answer.

It's possible to build android and iOS app in local ?

We can build the application with `expo build:android` and `expo build:ios` but these commands need an account and **send the source code in server of expo**.

I see it's possible to eject the app and folder android and iOS are created but after that I keep the possibility to develop with expo ? If I modify a javascript code I can recreate again the android and iOS folder ? or I need to develop in native code ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build Expo APK local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438857/how-to-build-expo-apk-local)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, If you eject the app, you can't develop with expo. But, you can keep editing in javascript. There is no necessity to develop in native code.