# Can I not use Expo (cloud service) at all using React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have build an app using react native(detached) but the thing is I would want to completely get rid of Expo. The reason is, what if one day EXPO service get shut down or no more supported.

So in this case I would not want the app to be affected.

Currently I need to publish my app thru ExpoKit to see the latest changes, how would I build my android app so it would not have any reference to Expo but still be able to work properly

Currently this is how I understand how the react native and expo works: first u build ur app using react native code and then a bundle.js is generated somewhere on cloud(EXPO) using publish command so the app communicate with that bundle.js.

Note I am not using any feature from Expo so why would I need Expo in this case?

Edited: If I am detaching my app from expo, I mean why would I still need Expo? Can't I just build the app and run the app without expo at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your whole application without using expo, just follow the steps from [facebook documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) in  "**Building Projects with Native Code**" tab.

or

you can run "**npm run eject**" in your project root directory folder.

After this, you can build your appliaction using react-native cli commands, like 
`react-native run-android`.

edited :--
For building apk for production, you can follow steps given in facebook documentation as [generating signed apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#docsNav) and for released IPA for iOS yo can follow [building your app for production for IOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production).

Comment: but still my app is relying on expo for running. I mean can I get rid of expo at all.

Comment: if you run npm run eject command, then it doesn't rely on EXPO for running in device or simulator.

Comment: but how about production? I mean its fine while development mode, what if you send the apk to someone it will not work cz u need to have some bundle.js running for ur app!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native

Comment: yeah that's right, @Mizlul you can follow the above comment's link, or you can do it by following this link "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#docsNav"