# How to generate a standalone signed APK from react native application, with detached expo?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

We are building a mobile application in [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), with the support of [Expo](https://expo.io/). After some time we decided to detach the expo to use other native benefits along with expo. It supports both the platforms, `Android` and `IOS`

I was able to detach our application successfully from the expo, using the instructions mentioned [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach). We have got `android` and `ios` folder with us and everything is working fine.

Now, we want to generate a standalone signed APK from the application. I am referring [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) for the steps. It does produce the APK but, somehow, its not working after installation on the device. Post install, if I try to open the app it gives error screen with the message,

> could not load the app

Sharing the screenshot below

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Before coming to StackOverflow's `Aks Question` stage, I did follow many post/questions but seems like unfortunately, they ain't helping me.
here are few,

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
- [How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)
  [this does not use expo..]
- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/212 [this guy plays with emotion...
  he said he was able to resolve the issue but, he ain't willing to share
  the solution]
- https://forums.expo.io/t/could-not-load-app-signed-apk-in-app-store-internal-testing-detached-app/9855

  and many more...

How can I resolve this issue? Any suggestions/pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after spending a couple of more hours I got the root cause of the issue. It was a minor one but, there are high chances to happen while development.

Actually, our application was containing two `expo` accounts in it. This happened mistakenly while development. Having the unique `expo` account in the application did solve my issue.