# How can I install a React Native app without releasing it to any store?

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, mobile-application

I wanna be able to use my app on my iPhone or my Android phone without the need of releasing it to App Store or Google Play Store.

Comment: What do you mean in 'use'? Just install it? Then for android you can create an apk and install it.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Answer (score 1):

or just use EXPO tools if you are open to using expo development environment for react native

Answer (score 1):

If your project is based on React-Native-CLI and your development environment is all set-up then just run command 'react-native run-android' in the terminal. It will generate a debug apk file which you can be found in the directory:

> android > app > build > outputs > apk > debug > app-debug.apk

You can directly install this debug apk in your android phone by connecting the device in the debugging mode and run the above command!

Answer (score 0):

> In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences, described in
>   Adding Your Apple ID Account in Xcode.
>
> In the project navigator, select the project and your target to
>   display the project editor.
>
> Click General and choose your name from the Team pop-up menu.
>
> Connect the device to your Mac and choose your device from the Scheme
>   toolbar menu.
>
> Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.
>
> Xcode creates a free provisioning profile for you and the warning text
>   under the Team pop-up menu disappears.
>
> Click the Run button.
>
> Xcode installs the app on the device before launching the app.

[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Answer (score 0):

For IOS you must have a developer account firstly. And then, you can send your app to itunesconnect and get the app from testflight. Or You can run your ios app on device by using cable. But you dont run your app in developer mode.

For android you just need get the apk from android studio. But some steps there are. Follow this steps for get the apk.

[How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native/47201001#47201001)

Answer (score 0):

You can Side load your react native app in iPhone or iPad using Xcode

1. Open `your_projectname.xcworkspace` from ios folder in Xcode
2. XCode - Choose your destination device simulator or device from
   Product -> Destination -> Select the device
3. Create a Temporary provision profile From project Target -> Signing
   &  Capabilities (Required only for physical device, for simulator don't
   require this)
4. Build and Run your project

Answer (score -2):

[React Native's official site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) has a guide on how to install your app without releasing it.

The tl;dr is as follows:

**For ios**:

```
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

**For android**:

```
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```