# How I can use my React Native app on Iphone?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, app-store

I am bulding my first react native app to give as a present of Mother's Day to my mother. But I found a problem, how can I install the app in my mother's iphone? I don't want to pay the 99$ dollar fee yet to Apple Developer Program. How can I do that for free and not depending of my computer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53362982/2873538

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with react-native, you have to open the XCode project of your app, located on `ios/projectname.xcworkspace`. Then, you can achieve this by connecting the iPhone on your Mac computer, and simply build/run the app on the iPhone real device by using XCode. This will install the application on the iPhone. After the build, your app will be installed on the iPhone and will run without your computer.

You can find more informations about building app on iPhone with XCode, with the followed documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-the-simulator-or-on-a-device