# I want to generate an apk of my react app, but i dont want to install android studio

Tags: react-native, ionic2

I want to generate an apk of my react app, but i dont want to install android studio.
I want to generate apk for ionic app too.
Can anyone show me latest way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate .apk you don't need android studio.
You can do it with the command line using any terminal just some changes in the andriod folder

Follow the [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) to make sure you follow proper steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a keystore file

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

After this : 
The link below has everything..

[How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)