# compile apk on a folder "Android" already created previously in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native, I've seen tutorials but everyone uses expo. I downloaded this project where they don't use expo. I want to compile this application for android, to finally get an .apk

[image: re]
[image]

This application already has a folder called "Android" but inside it does not have its respective .apk. How can I generate it?

this is the repository:

https://github.com/zsajjad/BusinessCard

It would be great if you can attach screenshots of how I should do it

**Note**. I have the latest version of android studio and I don't see the option of "build"

commands like "gradlew" from the console, they don't work, it's as if I didn't have that command installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)

Comment: you'd need to install Gradle for `gradlew` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Following instructions for build apk using android studio

1. Hope you installed node and react native on your machine. If not
   please follow the link to install it.[Install node and react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)
2. open your command prompt or terminal and redirect to your download project - `cd /Businesscard Master (change it according to your project location)`
3. Now enter -  `npm install`
4. Enter - `react-native link`
5. Follow the android related linking instructions on following link [react native camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)
   Hope you know about android camera and storage permissions.
6. same thing for [react native text detector](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector). Because your downloaded project have that packages in package.json
7. **Now open your project android folder in android studio using open existing android project.**
8. Then select build your project from android studio build menu and run it also
9. Generate apk using build menu- same process you have to follow for native android project

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the CLI, that's needlessly complicated and it obscures what Android Studio is actually doing. Here's all you need to do.

1. Open the whole /Android/ folder in Android Studio. This is your "project" similar to how you open a *.xed file in XCode. Except in Android Studio, you just open up the whole folder to get the build.
2. Android Studio will now prepare your project using Gradle. If there are any errors in the preparation it will tell you about them. Assuming your gradle and Android Studio versions are compatible and you got no errors, you're now ready to emulate, debug and create a production build. At this point the workflow is similar to using XCode. You'll see emulators under Tools -> AVD Manager.
3. In the file menus go to Build->Generate APK. You can choose between signed APKs, debug APKs and so on. You'll need the key file if you're signing the APK on your computer, otherwise there's also Google Play signing after you upload the APK.

TL;DR: Just open your /Android/ folder in Android Studio.

Side note: When Android Studio gives you popups to upgrade stuff don't do it. **NEVER upgrade Gradle or Android Studio** unless the RN / Expo team specifically ask you. This will break your whole project and you will need to rebuild the platform.