# how to one command build react-native to create android package file?

Tags: react-native

I am going through this tutorial https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup but I am surprised to find that is more the Development environment not Build environment instructions.  I can't find the android apk file anywhere.

What is the single command I run to create the apk file each time?  I want to make my automated build around that as well as some run all tests command.

I tried xgradlew build from the android directory but alas, that did not work.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46170797/2671901

It outputs the apk under `android/app/build/outputs/apk/`