# React Native : Generating apk file

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

I have built my very simple first React Native app with expo CLI. Now I want to know if I can generate a APK file. I don't want to publish it anywhere.
Can I generate the APK?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For expo, while you are still in your project folder, just enter the command

```
expo build:android
```

Comment: In this way, I would need to create a Expo account??

Comment: Yes, I strongly recommend you to create an Expo account (it is very convenient for development). After that, you can use all the related services

Comment: Oh! Thanks for letting me know