# React Native: How can i let my team test my app

Tags: react-native

I have a react native application. How can I let my teammate test my app just like sending a `.apk` file to them? Or drop the app into the test environment something like that. Thank you

Comment: You can have a look to this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you can simply generate `.apk` file of that application, to do so, I'd suggest reading following article:

https://www.instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/

And of course, last part of it says you can publish it to Google Play (which I assume you don't want to), you don't have to, you can just send that file to your friend by uploading that `.apk` file onto some uploading service (you can use Google Drive, Dropbox, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can read this Documentation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/testing-overview